# Recaptcha js error in checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.3, recaptcha

I got the latest version of magento 2.4.3-p1 and I am getting this js error in the checkout:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return renderReCaptcha() }"
    Message: this.settings is undefined
        initCaptcha http://mytheme.local/static/version1637251618/frontend/Magento/Mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha.js:117
        renderReCaptcha http://mytheme.local/static/version1637251618/frontend/Magento/Mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha.js:182
        afterRender http://mytheme.local/static/version1637251618/frontend/Magento/Mytheme/nl_NL/knockoutjs/knockout.js line 3221 > Function:3
        init http://mytheme.local/static/version1637251618/frontend/Magento/Mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/after-render.js:17
```

Does anyone know what is the reason behind that js error ?

Comment: The capcha js might load too fast may be ? There might be a trick with with defer to make sure it loads at the end I think.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a core bug. The fixed can be found here:

https://github.com/magento/security-package/pull/302/files.

I've made a composer patch for it and now it works.